# javascript setInterval gives error when called on an array object

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am creating a game in javascript. When user clicks UP arrow it launches a missile. User should be able to click the UP arrow and each click should launch a new missile. I have a 'missile' object and an array of 'missile's. Missile object has a launch function.

The below line gives me an error when used inside setInterval. It works without issue when I comment out the setInterval.

Error message: game.js:21

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at game.js:21

Line with error: `this.image.style.left=this.leftPos+'px';`

```
var missile = {
    leftPos: 0,
    bottomPos: 0,
    image: null,
    id: null,
    launch: function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            this.image.style.left = this.leftPos + 'px';
            this.image.style.bottom = this.bottomPos + 'px';
            this.leftPos += 0.5;
            this.bottomPos += 1;
        }, 10);
    }
};
```

Somewhere down I call this:
    currMissile=missiles[missiles.length-1];
    currMissile.launch();

Comment: ‘this’ is not what you think it is. The function supplied to setInterval is not executed on the same object context. Search for “javascript self this” or “javascript bind”.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

The context this is not referencing to the object `missile`, further, I can see you're filling an array with the same object multiple times, this means all indexes in the array are pointing to the same object which relies on errors.

You should *instantiate a new object* every time the user presses UP.

**For example**

```js
var Missile = function() {
  this.leftPos = 0;
  this.bottomPos = 0;
  this.image = { // Example
    style: {
      left: 4,
      bottom: 34
    }
  };
  this.id = null;
  this.launch = function() {
    setInterval(() => { // Use arrow function to get access to Missile lexical context.
      this.image.style.left = this.leftPos + 'px';
      this.image.style.bottom = this.bottomPos + 'px';
      this.leftPos += 0.5;
      this.bottomPos += 1;
      console.log(this.image.style.left);
    }, 500);
  };
};

new Missile().launch();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```